# Objects created while throwing new Exception()

Tags: java, object, exception

I have a class

```
public class TestDog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog();
        Dog d2 = new Dog();
        Dog d3 = d2;
        //how many objects created ? at this line.
    }
}
```

and a test class:

```
public class Dog {
    public Dog() {
        try{
            throw new Exception() ;
        } catch( Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I have doubt about how many objects created in the entire process? Please clarify.

Comment: *I need to know how many objects created after Dog d2 is assigned to d3* why do you think there would be any created after that?

Comment: because of  throw new Exception() in constructor;

Comment: And what makes you believe that it would be created after Dog d2 is assigned to d3?

Comment: You should read Peter Lawrey's blog post ["Common misconception: How many objects does this create?"](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/common-misconception-how-many-objects.html) which addresses the folly of such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, there are only 2 objects created. Assigning a reference to another reference does not create a new object. Also, here are some additional points:

- Although a new `Exception` object gets created in the constructor, it's a local object and does not propagate back to caller and hence, it becomes eligible for garbage collection (or might get garbage collected already by the time `d2` gets assigned, depending on when garbage collector runs) immediately after constructor finishes.
- If you assign `Exception` object to any reference in the `Dog` class then yes, there will be 2 more `Exception` objects created (and alive).

Comment: *after Dog d2 is assigned to d3* ?

Comment: Yes, there will be 3 **references** but only 2 **objects**.

Comment: I need one confirmation, if throw new Exception() will create New object in Heap memory or not.

Comment: @JangbahadurPatel Yes, it will. But it will immediately get destroyed once constructor finishes.

Comment: if yes, then there should be 4 objects created ? at the end.

Comment: Nope, **in the end** is important here. 4 get created and 2 get destroyed immediately, so only 2.

Comment: ok, Thanks @Darshan

Comment: @JangbahadurPatel you can accept the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

From your code we see that we throw `Exception`, but catch it and handle - do nothing block after `catch`.

And we will create 2 Dog objects - by `new`.

Comment: plus 2 Exception objects. They go out of scope and will be collected by GC at some point in time. But they are *created*.